# How to compute correlation of all subset of two vectors in R?

Tags: r, time-series, subset, apply, correlation

I work in R. I have two vectors of length `n`, let's say `a` and `b`. I want compute the correlation of all subsets of length `m`, in this way:

```
cor(a[1:m],b[1:m])
cor(a[m+1:2m],b[m+1:2m]) 
...
cor(a[km+1:n],b[km+1:n])
```

Now I'm using a cycle for but it's too slow. How can I do it in a faster way?

Comment: The syntax suggests you use matlab anyway.... http://de.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/43967-circular-cross-correlation-using-fft/content/xcorr_fft.m

Answer (score 2):

First create a grouping variable (`index`) and then calculate the correlations groupwise:

```
# Some fake data:
set.seed(123)
df <- data.frame(cbind(a = rnorm(100), b = rnorm(100), index = rep(1:10, each = 10)))

# Loading the pryr package:
library(plyr)

ddply(df, .(index), summarise, "corr" = cor(a, b))
   index        corr
1      1  0.26831285
2      2  0.14373593
3      3  0.21555988
4      4 -0.27461416
5      5 -0.08825786
6      6 -0.58680476
7      7 -0.02613450
8      8 -0.29408586
9      9  0.12030810
10    10 -0.04391428
```

Or with the `dplyr`:

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% group_by(index) %>% summarise(cor(a,b))
```

Or with the `data.table`:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[,cor(a, b), by = index]
```

Comment: The problem stays, the length of my vector is 3172000, the length of my subset 61. The script is still running.

Comment: How long does it last? The second version is the fastest for me, it lasts less than a second.